# Should I wear a cup for skateboarding?

Tags: skateboarding

Should I wear a cup for [skateboarding](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skateboard)?

Answer (score 2):

Testicular injuries are unlikely when skateboarding aside from rails. A cup will restrict your movement and possibly make things worse since it could slip and catch something. The things you want to worry about are your head and to a lesser extent your joints.

Comment: Im not wearing a cup i will do what you said ?. .